Condition that guarantees a tensor b-spline surface is not self-intersecting?
I saw this post, which is similar to what I want. However, it received no answer that meets my needs.
Is there a condition on the control points of a 2D tensor b-spline surface that will guarantee it is not self-intersecting?
For example, if the surface generated by the control-point lattice is self-intersection-free, does that tell us anything useful about the corresponding surface?
